# Wordpress - Making text within a div editable for cliënt

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, client, division

I made a DIV within the header of my WordPress theme. Within this DIV there are two  headers with some text in it (title and description of a current offer) I want the client to be able to edit this the text within this DIV region. I can't find an easy way to just make some text within a DIV editable.

Is there an easy way? making a new page template isn't an easy way I think, because the DIV is within the html code of my header, it's not a custom post within WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your way around WordPress you could create a new [sidebar widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets) and inject that sidebar into your header.

The client could edit the text in the Widget area of the admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery. When you click the div, replace the div, with an textarea.